# Peewee MySQL use join and union together

Tags: mysql, orm, peewee

I have 4 tables, A1, A2, B1, and B2, where A1 and A2 have exactly the same structure, and so does B1 and B2.

I want to union A1 and A2 as t1, B1 and B2 as t2, then t1 left join t2

The SQL I am using is

select * from (select * from A1 union select * from A2) t1 left join (select * from B1 union select * from B2) t2 on t1.key = t2.key;

1. Is this the normal way to do so?
2. How to achieve the same result using peewee?

E.g.:

```
A1: a1, a2(key=1), a3(key=2), a4
A2: a5, a6(key=3), a7, a8
B1: b1(key=1), b2(key=2), b3
B2: b4(key=3)
```

rst:

a1, a2+b1, a3+b2, a4, a5, a6+b4, a7, a8

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help your question.

Comment: Usually you want `union all`, not the default `union distinct`

Comment: Showing the peewee code you gave might encourage someone to show you how to do it.  The peewee doc was fairly clear